# Rails - How do I run a loop inside of a mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

So it turns out mailers hate loop inside of them. So here's my loop.

```
- for ["love", "hate", "war"].each do |f|
  = f
```

Which returns this went sent through actionmailer in rails 2.3.5 :

```
promotion_reminder.html.haml:17: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...ry_temp));}\n", 0, false);end;_hamlout.push_text("      </di...

On line #17 of app/views/notifier/promotion_reminder.html.haml

14:         
15:         - for ["love", "hate", "war"].each do |f|
16:           = f
```

How would you accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I woke up with the stupids this morning. I think you should all get yourself tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with using both `for` and `each`. Try this:

```
- ["love", "hate", "war"].each do |f|
  = f
```

or this:

```
- for f in ["love", "hate", "war"] do
  = f
```

I don't use haml. Does it need `end` to close block?

Comment: No. One of the great conveniences of Haml is that you don't explicitly close the blocks. You use the white space instead and Haml creates your blocks behind the scenes.

Comment: haml uses significant whitespace to close blocks.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
- ["love", "hate", "war"].each do |f|
  = f
```

and watch your white sapce

Answer (score 1):

```
- ["love", "hate", "war"].each do |f|
  = f
```